# Check in React JS if a checkbox is active or not

Tags: reactjs

[image]I wrote the next code:

```js
class Data extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { checked: true };
  }
  changeF() {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
  }
  render() {
    var message;
    if (this.state.checked) {
      message = "checked";
    } else {
      message = "UNchecked";
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <p> i: {message}</p>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={this.changeF}
          defaultChecked={this.state.checked}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
var doc = document.getElementById("content");
ReactDOM.render(<Data />, doc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

It should display "checked" when i will check the checkbox and "unchecked if not". Who can explain, why the app is not working?

Comment: You need to change the state using a callback. Like this:
`this.setState((prevState) => 
  ({ checked: !prevState.checked })
)`. Also change  `onChange={this.changeF}` to `onChange={this.changeF.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 1):

You need `checked` not `defaultChecked`:

```
 <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.changeF} checked={this.state.checked} />
```

Also when defining a method/function in a React class-component, you should be cognizant of the `this` keyword. In the `changeF` function you defined above, you are trying to update state by using `this.setState()`. However, if you actually tried to `console.log(this)` within `changeF`, you will get `undefined`, so naturally you cannot use `this.setState()`

Within `changeF` we need to point the `this` keyword to your component somehow, either by using an arrow-function which has lexical-binding, **OR** by explicitly `binding` the `this` keyword belonging to the `changeF` function inside the component's constructor.

Try turning `changeF` into an arrow-function, which will implicitly bind the `this` keyword to your component's execution context:

```
  changeF = () => {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
  }
```

See sandbox for working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-http-t480z

Ironically, now that you have a practical answer for your code, you probably now have more questions about `this`. It is arguably the most confusing topic in JavaScript.

**Here's a cheater's guide to understand the `this` keyword.**

Note: `this` almost always refers to nearest object that is a level above it/owns it.

Let's go through a couple of examples using your console.

1. **Printing `this`**

   **Code**: `console.log(this)`

   **Result**: `Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}`

There is a global window object, and when you simply print `this` without any wrapping objects, it points to the nearest one.

2. **Printing `this` within a `function()`**

   **Code**:

   ```
   function printSomething(){
           console.log(this)
       }

       printSomething()
   ```

   **Result**: `Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}`

Still, `this` points to the nearest object. The window.

3. **Printing `this` within a `function()` that is inside an object**

   **Code**:

   ```
   function nestedThis(){
           let myObj = {
              getThis: function(){
                  console.log(this)
              }
           }
           return myObj
       }

       nestedThis().getThis()
   ```

   **Result**: `{ getThis: ƒ}`

Nice! We aren't getting the window object anymore. Instead, now `this` refers to `myObj`, which is the object that owns it.

Now to understand why your `changeF` function did not work:

```
  changeF() {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
  }
```

In the context of a React component, the `this` keyword is not immediately given a value. It will not inherently receive the `window` object, hence React component's have their own execution scope. And since it cannot find an `object` at a level above it, in a sense `this` becomes "lost".

As a workaround, you will see people binding their traditional functions so that the `this` keyword points to the component context.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { checked: true };

    this.changeF = this.changeF.bind(this)
  }
```

*Note: Within the constructor, the `this` keyword is defined and you have access to all the class properties.*

But why the heck do **arrow-functions** `() => {}` work? Well arrow-functions have something called lexical-scoping. Which essentially just means that when you call `this` inside the function, it will point to the overarching execution context.

Comment: @Asking sorry about that. See my solution above and also working sandbox :)

Comment: the code doesn't work, even if i inserted all your changes

Comment: Seems to be working fine in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-http-t480z @Asking

Comment: when i run the code on my browser i get the error from the image above

Comment: @Asking that is just weird, alternatively you can just bind the function to your constructor. See the last bit of code I wrote towards the end about constructor.