# Add value from input into array is not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and wanted to add value from input into array but nothing happens when I try to achieve that. GUYS IF SOMETHING IS NOT CLEAR PLEASE LET ME KNOW. Here is the code I am using:

```
class Engine extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let types = ["Diesel", "Gazoline", "Simple"];
    return (
      <div>
        <Car type={types} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Car extends React.Component {
  openm(e) {
    let addItem = e.target.elements.type.value;

    if (addItem) {
      this.props.type.push(additem);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          {this.props.type.map((item, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{item}</p>;
          })}
        </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.openm}>
          <input type="text" name="type" />
          <button>Remo all</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const box = document.querySelector(".mir");

ReactDOM.render(<Engine />, box);
```

If you look at the code in Car class's openm method, I am trying to get access to array via props.

Comment: You should never directly mutate props or state, like you do here: `this.props.type.push(additem)`. React won't detect direct mutations (and hence won't re-render), and it can cause erroneous behaviour. Also your `types` aren't in state, it's just some variable in the render function. You should put them in the _state_ of `Engine`, then pass down a function for updating them using `setState()` to the `Car` child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code and I'll try to explain them as thoroughly as possible.

1) Props are immutable. Which means that you cannot alter them by doing something like `this.props.types.push(blah)`. That would not cause any visual changes or re-rendering to your application. It would appear as if nothing happened.

**Solution**: Employ React-state instead, which to put simply can be understood as a tracking mechanism that each component owns, to keep track of the status and data of a component. Instead, of defining a types array in your render, define one in state instead. Then we can freely add on to that array. Whenever the state of a component is updated, the component re-renders to reflect those changes if required.

2) The importance of the `this` keyword. Component methods need to be bound to the component's execution context in order for the `this` keyword to work as expected. Further reading: [Check in React JS if a checkbox is active or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215382/check-in-react-js-if-a-checkbox-is-active-or-not)

**Solution**: Define `open` as an arrow-function so that the `this` keyword is implicitly bound to the component. Thus giving you accessing to `this.setState()` and `this.props.`

3) Forms will naturally refresh the page upon submission. You don't want that in this sceniario.

**Solution**: use `event.preventDefault()`

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-pine-c0ied

Full code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class Engine extends React.Component {
  state = {
    types: ["Diesel", "Gazoline", "Simple"]
  };

  addItem = item => {
    this.setState({
      types: [...this.state.types, item]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Car type={this.state.types} addItem={this.addItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Car extends React.Component {
  open = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let addItem = e.target.elements.type.value;

    if (addItem) {
      this.props.addItem(addItem);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          {this.props.type.map((item, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{item}</p>;
          })}
        </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.open}>
          <input type="text" name="type" />
          <button>Remo all</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const box = document.querySelector(".mir");

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Engine />, rootElement);
```

Comment: hi Christopher thank you for your great and profound answer. I have a mere question. Why if we try to access this.props inside render() all works ok. But if we try to access this.props in, say, open method we get error saying "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined". Thank you

Comment: @Dickens good question. It's because `render` is a lifecycle method that comes with React. Simply, put the `this` keyword in a lifecycle method is already bound to the component. If you read closely, the error says "props" of undefined, which is referring to `this`. When you define a function and use the `this` keyword inside of it, `this` refers to the closest object one level above the it (a level above the function). Since this is a component, there is no object at that level. Therefore `this` is undefined. However, an arrow-function would resolve this since it points this to the component.

Comment: thank you Christopher for again such a profound answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be mutating the values either in props or have local variables within render since they will be overwritten when a re-render occurs. Instead have the data in state and update it using a handler

```
class Engine extends React.Component {
  state = {
     types: ["Diesel", "Gazoline", "Simple"]
  }
  addTypes = (value) => {
     this.setState(prev => ({
          types: prev.types.concat(value)
     }))
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Car type={this.state.types} addTypes={this.addTypes} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Car extends React.Component {
  openm(e) {
    let addItem = e.target.elements.type.value;

    if (addItem) {
      this.props.addTypes(additem);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          {this.props.type.map((item, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{item}</p>;
          })}
        </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.openm}>
          <input type="text" name="type" />
          <button>Remo all</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const box = document.querySelector(".mir");

ReactDOM.render(<Engine />, box);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly add values to `props`. You need to maintain your data in state, and have a function to add data in parent component only. Pass that function to child component and call that function fromm child with new value.

```
class Engine extends React.Component {
  state={
    types : ["Diesel", "Gazoline", "Simple"]
  }

  addItem = (value) => {
    this.setState(prevState=>({
      ...prevState,
      types: prevState.types.concat(value)
    }))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Car type={this.state.types} addItem={this.addItem}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Car extends React.Component {
  openm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let item = e.target.elements.type.value;
    if (item) {
      this.props.addItem(item);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          {this.props.type.map((item, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{item}</p>;
          })}
        </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.openm.bind(this)}>
          <input type="text" name="type" />
          <button>Remo all</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-derzmh)

**Note:** In  `openm` function don't forgot to add `e.preventDefault();`, otherwise it will refresh your page.
Also you need to bind your function like, `this.openm.bind(this)`